# R remove rows, that hasn't got the same value in two columns

Tags: r, subset

Sorry for asking stuff that should be an easy job, I am a geology student, triing to use R for his work in school.

I'd like to remove the rows from my database, where the value at two certain columns do not match.

example:

```
e F 14 14
t D 14 12
j A 11 11
a R 14 13
```

So the second row should be removed and the forth as well. The column with the letters should not be relevant, just the two with the numbers.

Comment: something like `df[df$col3==df$col4,]`

Comment: something like `subset(df, df$Col3 == df$Col4)`

Answer (score 1):

suppose your data is store in df, to do following:

```
df <- data.frame(col1= c('e','t','j','a'),
                 col2 =c('F','D','A','R'),
                 col3=c(14,14,11,14),
                 col4=c(14,12,11,13))
df <- df[df$col3==df$col4,]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple `subset` operation:

```
new_df <- subset(df, columnX == columnY)
```

Answer (score -1):

So assume the rows that you want to remove is 2,3

The key idea is you form a set of the rows you want to remove, and keep the complement of that set.

In R, the complement of a set is given by the '-' operator.

So, assuming the data.frame is called myData:

```
myData <- myData[-c(2, 3), ]
```